# Am I using scipy.linalg.solve_discrete_lyapunov correctly

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using `scipy.linalg.solve_discrete_lyapunov` to compute matrix *P* from

*M<sup>T</sup> PM - P = -Q* where *M = A - BK* and *Q = I*

(see below and also see  [Lyapunov Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation)). However, for the computed *P* I get *M<sup>T</sup> PM - P ≠ - Q*.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp 

A = np.array([[-1.86194971, 3.49237959],[-2.34245904, 3.86194971]])
B = np.array([[ 3000., 2500.5], [ 2000.2, 3000.]])
K = np.array([[ 0.0001367, -0.00016844], [-0.00069637, 0.0009627]])
I = np.array([[1., 0.],[0., 1.]])

# Eigenvalues of A are (0.9, 1.1)
# Eigenvalues of A-BK are (0.29, 0.49) (i.e. A-BK is Schur)

P = sp.linalg.solve_discrete_lyapunov(A-np.dot(B,K), I)

# P= [[ 6.61311138  4.32497891]
#     [ 4.32497891  4.36910499]]

# But after checking (A-BK)^TP(A-BK)-P, that is 

J = np.dot((A.transpose()-np.dot(K.transpose(),B.transpose())),np.dot(P,A-np.dot(B,K)))-P

# I get the following
# J = (A-BK)^TP(A-BK)-P = [[ -1.11929701 -19.5567893 ]
#                          [-19.5567893   37.89911723]]
#                   
# Not equal to -I?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `M = A - np.dot(B,K)`. Then `solve_discrete_lyapunov(M, I)` is solving

```
np.dot(M, np.dot(P, M.T)) - P = -I
```

---

```
In [64]: M = A - np.dot(B,K)

In [65]: np.dot(M, np.dot(P,M.T)) - P
Out[65]: 
array([[ -1.00014927e+00,  -9.93418066e-05],
       [ -9.93418066e-05,  -1.00006419e+00]])

In [66]: np.allclose(np.dot(M, np.dot(P,M.T)) - P, -I, atol=0.001)
Out[66]: True
```

---

If you want to solve

```
np.dot(M.T, np.dot(P, M)) - P + I = 0
```

then call

```
P = solve_discrete_lyapunov(M.T, I)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Maybe I'm overlooking something very simple but shouldn't 'scipy.linalg.solve_discrete_lyapunov' be solving _np.dot(M.T,np.dot(P,M)) - P + I = 0_ (see also [Discrete Lyapunov Equation - SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_discrete_lyapunov.html)); because, _np.dot(M, np.dot(P,M.T)) - P = -I_ is a different equation, _M<sup>T</sup> PM_ is not equal to _MPM<sup>T</sup>_. Again, maybe I'm overlooking something very simple, in any case thank you for your help and any further assistance.

Comment: Thanks once more for a quick reply. According to [Discrete Lyapunov Equation - SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_discrete_lyapunov.html) if you want to solve `np.dot(M.T,np.dot(P,M)) - P = - I` you call `solve_discrete_lyapunov(M,I)`...

Comment: Yes, I agree the documentation says that. However, the empirical evidence suggests otherwise. (Note: I haven't tried to grok the source code algorithm, nor do I have a recent enough version of scipy to test `solve_discrete_lyapunov`. I'm merely going by the single computation shown above.)

Comment: Hi again. I think that [Discrete Lyapunov Equation - SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_discrete_lyapunov.html) is writen for row vectors, since for row system, i.e., `x(k+1)=x(k)M` (`x` is a row vector), _Lyapunov_ equation is `np.dot(M, np.dot(P,M.T)) - P = - Q`. So, as you suggested, if you want to solve `np.dot(M.T, np.dot(P,M)) - P = -Q` (i.e., for "column system" `x(k+1) = Mx(k)` (`x` now column vector)) you call `P = solve_discrete_lyapunov(M.T,Q)`...